# Independence of random variable comparisons

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent continuous random variables with equal distributions, are the two events $X\leq Y$ and $X\leq Z$ independent?

I know that $$P(X\leq Y)P(X\leq Z)=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P(X\leq x)f_X(x) dx}\right)^2$$
but I can't figure out how to solve $P(X\leq Y,X\leq Z)$ to check for independence.

Comment: Note that $P(X\leq Y,X\leq Z)$ equals the triple integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_x^{\infty}\int_x^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(y)f_Z(z)dzdydx$$

Comment: Are you sure it's true?  Heuristically, If $X$ is very large then both $P(X\le Y)$ and $P(X\le Z)$ would both be small.  In other words, there seem to be correlation between these events.

Comment: All 6 relative orderings (such as $X<Y<Z$ and $Z<X<Y$ and so on) are equally likely.  Independence would imply $(1/2)(1/2)=(1/3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $$\mathsf P(X\leq Y)\mathsf P(X\leq Z) =\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_s^\infty f(s)f(t)\mathrm d t\mathrm d s\right)^2$$

$$\mathsf P(X\leq Y,X\leq Z) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_s^\infty\int_s^\infty f(s)f(t)f(u)\mathrm d u\mathrm d t\mathrm d s$$

---

But you might have more luck with:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leq Y) ~&=~\mathsf P(X\leq Y\leq Z)+\mathsf P(X\leq Z\leq  Y)+\mathsf P(Z\leq X\leq Y)\\\mathsf P(X\leq Z) ~&=~\mathsf P(X\leq Y\leq Z)+\mathsf P(X\leq Z\leq  Y)+\mathsf P(Y\leq X\leq Z)\\\mathsf P(X\leq Y, X\leq Z) ~&=~ \mathsf P(X\leq Y\leq Z)+\mathsf P(X\leq Z\leq Y)\end{align}$$

Also, since the variables $X,Y,Z$ are iid, they are interchangeable, so ...